# list comprehension to build a nested dictionary from a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have data (counts) indexed by `user_id` and `analysis_type_id` obtained from a database. It's a list of 3-tuple. Sample data:

```
counts  = [(4, 1, 4), (3, 5, 4), (2, 10, 4), (2, 10, 5)]
```

where the first item of each tuple is the `count`, the second the `analysis_type_id`, and the last the `user_id`.

I'd like to place that into a dictionary, so i can retrieve the counts quickly: given a `user_id` and `analysis_type_id`. It would have to be a two-level dictionary. Is there any better structure?

To construct the two-level dictionary "by hand", I would code:

```
dict = {4:{1:4,5:3,10:2},5:{10:2}}
```

Where `user_id` is the first dict key level, `analysis_type_id` is the second (sub-) key, and the `count` is the value inside the dict.

How would I create the "double-depth" in dict keys through list comprehension? 
Or do I need to resort to a nested for-loop, where I first iterate through unique `user_id` values, then find matching `analysis_type_id` and fill in the counts ... one-at-a-time into the dict?

Comment: You don't need to resort to using double depth. Just use a two tuple as your dictionary key directly. For example: `mydict[(4,1)] = 4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Two Tuple Keys

I would suggest abandoning the idea of nesting dictionaries and simply use two tuples as the keys directly. Like so:

```
d = { (user_id, analysis_type_id): count for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts}
```

The dictionary is a hash table. In python, each two tuple has a single hash value (not two hash values) and thus each two tuple is looked up based on its (relatively) unique hash. Therefore this is faster (2x faster, most of the time) than looking up the hash of TWO separate keys (first the `user_id`, then the `analysis_type_id`).

However, [beware of premature optimization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DubiousPython#Premature_Optimization). Unless you're doing millions of lookups, the increase in performance of the flat `dict` is unlikely to matter. The real reason to favor the use of the two tuple here is that the syntax and readability of a two tuple solution is far superior than other solutions- that is, assuming the vast majority of the time you will be wanting to access items based on a pair of values and not groups of items based on a single value.

### Consider Using a `namedtuple`

It may be convenient to create a named tuple for storing those keys. Do that this way:

```
from collections import namedtuple
IdPair = namedtuple("IdPair", "user_id, analysis_type_id")
```

Then use it in your dictionary comprehension:

```
d = { IdPair(user_id, analysis_type_id): count for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts}
```

And access a count you're interested in like this:

```
somepair = IdPair(user_id = 4, analysis_type_id = 1)
d[somepair]
```

The reason this is sometimes useful is you can do things like this:

```
user_id = somepair.user_id # very nice syntax
```

---

### Some Other Useful Options

One downside of the above solution is the case in which your lookup fails. In that case, you will only get a traceback like the following:

```
>>> d[IdPair(0,0)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: IdPair(user_id=0, analysis_type_id=0)
```

This isn't very helpful; was it the `user_id` that was unmatched, or the `analysis_type_id`, or both?

You can create a better tool for yourself by creating your own `dict` type that gives you a nice traceback with more information. It might look something like this:

```
class CountsDict(dict):
    """A dict for storing IdPair keys and count values as integers.

    Provides more detailed traceback information than a regular dict.
    """
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(k)
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise self._handle_bad_key(k, exc) from exc
    def _handle_bad_key(self, k, exc):
        """Provides a custom exception when a bad key is given."""
        try:
            user_id, analysis_type_id = k
        except:
            return exc
        has_u_id = next((True for u_id, _ in self if u_id==user_id), False)
        has_at_id  = next((True for _, at_id in self if at_id==analysis_type_id), False)
        exc_lookup = {(False, False):KeyError(f"CountsDict missing pair: {k}"),
                      (True, False):KeyError(f"CountsDict missing analysis_type_id: "
                                             f"{analysis_type_id}"),
                      (False, True):KeyError(f"CountsDict missing user_id: {user_id}")}
        return exc_lookup[(user_id, analysis_type_id)]
```

Use it just like a regular `dict`.

However, it may make MORE sense to simply add new pairs to your `dict` (with a count of zero) when you try to access a missing pair. If this is the case, I'd use a `defaultdict` and have it set the count to zero (using the default value of `int` as the factory function) when a missing key is accessed. Like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(default_factory=int, 
                      ((user_id, analysis_type_id), count) for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts))
```

Now if you attempt to access a key that is missing, the count will be set to zero. However, one problem with *this* method is that ALL keys will be set to zero:

```
value = my_dict['I'm not a two tuple, sucka!!!!'] # <-- will be added to my_dict
```

To prevent this, we go back to the idea of making a `CountsDict`, except in this case, your special `dict` will be a subclass of `defaultdict`. However, unlike a regular `defaultdict`, it will check to make sure the key is a valid kind before it is added. And as a bonus, we can make sure ANY two tuple that is added as a key becomes an `IdPair`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class CountsDict(defaultdict):
    """A dict for storing IdPair keys and count values as integers.

    Missing two-tuple keys are converted to an IdPair. Invalid keys raise a KeyError.
    """
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        try:
            user_id, analysis_type_id = k
        except:
            raise KeyError(f"The provided key {k!r} is not a valid key.")
        else:
            # convert two tuple to an IdPair if it was not already
            k = IdPair(user_id, analysis_type_id)
        return super().__getitem__(k)
```

Use it just like the regular `defaultdict`:

```
my_dict = CountsDict(default_factory=int, 
                     ((user_id, analysis_type_id), count) for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts))
```

NOTE: In the above I have not made it so that two tuple keys are converted to `IdPair`s upon instance creation (because `__setitem__` is not utilized during instance creation). To create this functionality, we would also need to implement an override of the `__init__` method.

### Wrap Up

Out of all of these, the more useful option depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: Nice! Much simpler. Do you know how it works under the hood, when I recall data? E.g. if I code `d[(4,1)]`, will python search through each combination of `(user_id,analysis_type_id)`) until it gets a hit?
I thought of the double-dict to make it efficient: only look though an handful of `user_id` to load the relevant sub-dict, then you only need to search through a handful of `analysis_type_id` to get the right count

Comment: Dictionary lookups are done via a hash table. That means Python essentially goes directly to the right entry, no matter how many entries there are (O(1) search time). Looking up via a tuple will be as fast as you can get, roughly twice as fast as looking up each entry in the tuple separately.

Comment: So do the two types of answers to my question:
1) a defaultdict with key depth 2, and
2) a "flat" dict of 2-tuples
are expected to have the same performance, in the end?

Comment: They will not have the same performance. The flat `dict` will perform roughly 2x faster most of the time, and it is very very unlikely to ever perform slower. However, unless you're doing millions of lookups, it is unlikely to matter. The syntax and readability of a two tuple solution is far superior, especially if you employ a `namedtuple` (which is wonderful a tool that should be utilized *liberally* in python).

Answer (score 2):

The most readable solution utilizes a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which saves you nested loops and bumpy checking if keys already exist:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(dict)  # do not shadow the built-in 'dict'
for x, y, z in counts:
    dct[z][y] = x
dct
# defaultdict(dict, {4: {1: 4, 5: 3, 10: 2}, 5: {10: 2}})
```

If you really want a one-liner comprehension you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and this clunkiness:

```
from itertools import groupby
dct = {k: {y: x for x, y, _ in g} for k, g in groupby(sorted(counts, key=lambda c: c[2]), key=lambda c: c[2])}
```

If your initial data is already sorted by user_id, you can save yourself the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for the `defaultdict` object. You can create a defaultdict whose elements are always dicts. Then you can just stuff the counts into the right dicts, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts  = [(4, 1, 4), (3, 5, 4), (2, 10, 4), (2, 10, 5)]
dct = defaultdict(dict)
for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts:
    dct[user_id][analysis_type_id]=count

dct
# defaultdict(dict, {4: {1: 4, 5: 3, 10: 2}, 5: {10: 2}})

# if you want a 'normal' dict, you can finish with this:
dct = dict(dct)
```

Or you can just use standard dicts with `setdefault`:

```
counts  = [(4, 1, 4), (3, 5, 4), (2, 10, 4), (2, 10, 5)]
dct = dict()
for count, analysis_type_id, user_id in counts:
    dct.setdefault(user_id, dict())
    dct[user_id][analysis_type_id]=count

dct
# {4: {1: 4, 5: 3, 10: 2}, 5: {10: 2}}
```

I don't think you can do this neatly with a list comprehension, but there's no need to be afraid of a for-loop for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following logic. It's no need to import any package, just we should use for loops properly.

`counts  = [(4, 1, 4), (3, 5, 4), (2, 10, 4), (2, 10, 5)]
dct = {x[2]:{y[1]:y[0] for y in counts if x[2] == y[2]} for x in counts }`

"""output will be  {4: {1: 4, 5: 3, 10: 2}, 5: {10: 2}} """

Answer (score 0):

You can list comprehension for nested loops with condition and use one or more of them for elements selections:

```
# create dict with tuples
line_dict = {str(nest_list[0]) : nest_list[1:] for nest_list in nest_lists for elem in nest_list if elem== nest_list[0]}
print(line_dict)

 # create dict with list 
line_dict1 = {str(nest_list[0]) list(nest_list[1:]) for nest_list in nest_lists for elem in nest_list if elem== nest_list[0]}
print(line_dict1)

Example: nest_lists = [("a","aa","aaa","aaaa"), ("b","bb","bbb","bbbb") ("c","cc","ccc","cccc"), ("d","dd","ddd","dddd")]

Output: {'a': ('aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'), 'b': ('bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb'), 'c': ('cc', 'ccc', 'cccc'), 'd': ('dd', 'ddd', 'dddd')}, {'a': ['aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'], 'b': ['bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb'], 'c': ['cc', 'ccc', 'cccc'], 'd': ['dd', 'ddd', 'dddd']}
```